# Harmonic function function on annulus

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I want to find $\phi(x, y)$ that is harmonic in the washer $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: 2 \leq|z-1-i| \leq 3\}$ and satisfies the boundary conditions $\phi(x, y)=5$ for $|z-1-i|=2$ and $\phi(x, y)=6$ for $|z-1-i|=3$.

I  convert this into PDE problem, but i don't think it is right method. Can someone help .

Answer (score 1):

The Laplacian in cylindrical coordinates is
$$
            \nabla^2f(r,\theta)=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial\theta^2}.
$$
If $f$ is a function of $r$ only, then
$$
              \nabla^2 f(r)=\frac{d^2f}{d r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{d f}{d r} = \frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{d r}\left(r\frac{d f}{d r}\right).
$$
So $f(r)$ is a solution of the Laplace equation if there are constants $C,D$ such that
$$
                r\frac{df}{dr}=C \\
                  f=C\ln(r)+D.
$$
If $f(r)$ satisfies
$$
     f(2)=5,\;\; f(3)=6,
$$
this determines $C$ and $D$, and gives a final solution
$$
                  \phi(x,y)=f(|(x,y)+(1,1)|)
$$

Answer (score 0):

You have the boundary condition $\phi$ is constant on $\lvert z-(1+i)\rvert$ constant, so an obvious choice is $\phi(z)=\alpha\log\lvert z-(1+i)\rvert+\beta$, some real constant $\alpha$, since this is $\operatorname{Re}[\alpha\log(z-(1+i))+\beta]$ locally the real part of a holomorphic function.